# Need notification sounds for all messages, including follow-up

Tags: notifications

With updated Lollipop on Samsung S4, the notification is sounded for the first message from a contact, but not any of the follow-up messages.  Annoying to constantly check for reply messages by unlocking the home screen with the phone in my hand all the time.  All settings are set to full sound and vibration.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since updating to lollipop.  You might try another app for messaging called Messages Plus which can be downloaded from the play store.  It will alert you after every response.  I'm not crazy about the format but at least it does alert you after each response.

Comment: Could you mention the link for this app?

Answer (score 0):

with Android if you go to Google Play and look for the app "messages plus", download and install, you can even customize  the screen so that you will have balloons instead of just colored lines on the side.balloons for you and the  responder can be made different colors and it will perform the same as the old app we used under KitKat or the other operating system but with this app you will get alerts each time the other party responds

Answer (score 0):

with Android just go to play store and type in messages plus. you can also customize it to have the different colored balloons for sender and responder as well as other customizations I don't know the actual link because I downloaded from Google Play Store. but if you go on to your computer and in Google search type messages plus you should be able to copy the link from there